# Multiple google accounts for Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-account

Google Colab allows to use a single GPU in a 12-hour runtime from the Google Account. Would it be considered a fair use to make multiple accounts on Google and run multiple Colab runtimes using those accounts for the scientific purpose? Or would it bring legal concerns and be considered the "abuse"? Terms allow to make multiple accounts as long as limitations are not bypassed, but this is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 2):

"Resources in Colab are prioritized for users who have recently used less resources, in order to prevent the monopolization of limited resources by a small number of users."

Answer (score 0):

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#gpu-availability is the most relevant writing on the subject I know of.